# Can not reach open edx studio at domain:18010

Tags: content-management-system, openedx

I have installed an openEdx production using tutor. The lms is running but I can't  access the cms using the port (domain name:18010).

The both services (lms/cms) are running.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the Tutor, please use the

studio.yourdomainname.com

Basically, it's the value of the CMS_HOST.